# I'm getting an error everytime I try to type mysqld into the command line

Tags: mysql, database

This one is stumping me bigtime...

> JohnnyRingo@Johns-MacBook-Pro:~$ mysqld
>
> mysqld: Can't change dir to '/usr/local/mysql-5.7.19-macos10.12-x86_64/data/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
> 2017-09-16T03:18:04.160020Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
> 2017-09-16T03:18:04.160358Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
> 2017-09-16T03:18:04.160429Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.19) starting as process 2451 ...
> 2017-09-16T03:18:04.164591Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.7.19-macos10.12-x86_64/data/Johns-MacBook-Pro.lower-test
> 2017-09-16T03:18:04.164629Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.7.19-macos10.12-x86_64/data/Johns-MacBook-Pro.lower-test
> 2017-09-16T03:18:04.164704Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to /usr/local/mysql-5.7.19-macos10.12-x86_64/data/
> 2017-09-16T03:18:04.164720Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
> 2017-09-16T03:18:04.164729Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
> 2017-09-16T03:18:04.164811Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

Comment: "Permission denied" try to sudo

Comment: Still not working. The response is below

Comment: "Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!" did you do that? Another option is to chown the directory: `chown -R JohnyRingo /usr/local/mysql-5.7.19-macos10.12-x86_64` then `mysqld #no sudo`

Comment: When i did that chown command all I got was a mess of "Operation is not permitted."

Comment: Couldn't find a way to run it as root. Or at least not a way that worked if I understood it right.

Comment: you have to `sudo` the `chown` (put sudo in front of the whole command)

Comment: You don't run `mysqld` directly, it has wrapper scripts like `mysqld_safe` to launch it correctly, and furthermore, you should have some `launchctl` script to do that anyway. Is this from Homebrew? If so: `brew info mysql` and look at the instructions at the bottom.

Comment: I'm a moron. Did that and when I ran mysqld again i received this... (check below)

Comment: If you're looking to recover the password *and* you have data you want to preserve *and* you don't have backups then [follow the official instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html). If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).